# Random int between 0 and 100 and a multiple of 12

Tags: c#

How would i go about making a random int, that is between 0 and 100 and a multiple of 12?

```
int RndInt = GetRandomInt(0, 100);
```

Comment: GetIntRandom(0, 8) * 12

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var rng = new Random();

int rndInt = rng.Next(0, 9) * 12;
```

Note that `rng.Next(min, max)` uses an *exclusive* upper bound for `max`.

Also note that `Random()` is seeded from the current time from the Real Time Clock which only updates every few milliseconds - so you should create a single Random object and reuse it; do not keep creating one in a tight loop because it will give you wrong results.

In general, if you want to produce random numbers between `0` and `N` with a step size of `S`:

1. Calculate the maximum number of steps you can get using integer division: `M = N/S;`
2. Calculate a random number between 0 and M inclusive.
3. Multiply that random number by the step size.

In your case:

```
S = 12
N = 100
M = 100/12 = 8
```

To generate a random number between 0 and M inclusive you can use `Random.Next(0, M+1)`. Note the `+1` that is needed because the `Random.Next()` expected an exclusive value for `max`.

Comment: You can use `rng.Next(9)`, but +1 for remembering that the upper bound is exclusive :-)

Comment: @DanPuzey Oh yes you're right, for some reason I always use the version with two parameters... I'm stuck in my habits. :)

Answer (score 7):

Generate a random integer between 0 and 8 and multiply it by 12.

Comment: Why is anyone downvoting this?

Comment: My guess is because you didn't post any actual code.

Comment: On simple thing like this I feel it better to let the guy find its own way. Simply copy/pasting code won't help him

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Random`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) class and [`Random.Next`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.next.aspx) method like;

```
Random r = new Random();
int i = r.Next(9) * 12;
Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/cRcndY).

As explanation, `r.Next(9)` returns an `int` from `0` to `9` (includes `0` not `9`).

Answer (score 0):

Just for funzies:

```
int ret = 0;
while ( (ret=rnd.Next(0,100))%12 != 0 ) ;
return ret;
```

Comment: In theory, the loop could run forever. Fun perhaps, but useless.

Comment: @Stijn It could if `Random` were a actual random number generator.

Comment: @p.s.w.g A truly random number generator does not exist, there's always at least one input parameter required. Unless `Random` attempts to reach uniform distribution, it is possible.

Comment: @Stijn I simply mean that it's a LCG-PRNG, so it's guaranteed to hit every number between 0 and 99 at least once in it's period.

Comment: @p.s.w.g. Afaik C# uses *subtractive PRNG* - is it a kind of LCG?

Comment: @p.s.w.g I've learned something today then :)

Comment: @Stijn I neve would have suspected that something good will come of my retarded answer;)

Comment: @Dariusz Most languages use an LCG for simple random numbers, I assumed C# did as well, thanks for correcting me. Actually, it's not! I wasn't familiar with that algorithm, so I looked up the source code. It doesn't look anything like an LCG, but it appears that it may have the same 'covering' characteristic. I tested it with ranges up to 1 million, and it covered them all. (obviously that's not a rigorous proof though)

Comment: @p.s.w.g apparently all people who commented on my retarded answer learned something. Imageine if Stephen Hawking commented... Infinite power source? Unified theory? ... ahh the possibilities...